# ld: framework not found nanopb

Tags: react-native

Al instalar el paquete de yarn add @react-native-firebase/app, he intentado de todo para buscar una solución al problema pero no he tenido éxito.

El problema que tengo es ld: framework not found nanopb

Comment: Bienvenido, revisa por favor [ask], considera agregar más información a tu pregunta. ¿es nanopb o FirebaseNanoPB?

Comment: Buen día mi problema es con ld: framework not found nanopb